# Pandas Apply with Idmax Incorrectly Converts Mixed Object Columns to Floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

So I have various columns in my dataset that are a mix of integers and strings. Trying to remove duplicates, I convert each column in the row to a string, get the length of it, and add that length as an extra column:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

r1 = [datetime.date(2016, 7, 10), 'M']
r2 = [datetime.date(2014, 11, 26), 0]
r3 = [datetime.date(2015, 8, 13), 'M']
r4 = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 11), 'OPSTC']
r5 = [datetime.date(2014, 1, 31), 'FMS']
df = pd.DataFrame([r1, r2, r3, r4, r5], columns=['date', 'mix'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def f(row):
    return(row.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))).sum())

df['width'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df

    date        mix     width
0   2016-07-10  M       20
1   2014-11-26  0       20
2   2015-08-13  M       20
3   2015-05-11  OPSTC   24
4   2014-01-31  FMS     22

for column in df.columns:
    print(column, df[column].dtype)

date  datetime64[ns]
mix   object
width int64
```

This does not create any problems. The problem happens when I group the rows and eliminate those that don't have the highest row total:

```
def f(rows):
    rows.applymap(str) # Even putting this in here has no effect!

    return(rows.ix[rows['width'].idxmax()])

df = df.groupby(['date'], as_index=False).apply(f)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

    date        mix width
0   2014-01-31  NaN 22
1   2014-11-26  0.0 20
2   2015-05-11  NaN 24
3   2015-08-13  NaN 20
4   2016-07-10  NaN 20
```

It is converting the mixed object columns to floats. You can group by either mix or date to reproduce the problem. Converting the columns to strings (either by using `.apply(str)` or `.astype(str)`) has no effect.

I am using Python 3.5.2.final.0 and Pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Much better question. If it's not answered by the time I get home, I should be able to help.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks! I'm stepping through the code now with IPython.core.debugger. Unfortunately the output gets garbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points of failure here

- failed to assign to variable

  ```
  def f(rows):
      rows.applymap(str)  # this doesn't get assigned
      return rows.ix[rows['width'].idxmax()]
  ```
- don't use `ix`.  Doesn't effect anything here.  But it will be deprecated.
- Super subtle and dangerous point... `row.ix[rows['width'].idxmax()]` returns a `pd.Series`.  Why is this important?  At the moment I can't nail down the entire story (I'm working on it).  But, when you return a `pd.Series` `pandas` is conducting some inferrecne and determined that `'mix'` ought to be numeric.  The `apply` method for a `groupby` object passes a `pd.DataFrame` object to the function being applied.  You can fix this by changign the scalar `rows['width'].idxmax()` to the array-like `[rows['width'].idxmax()]`

  ```
  def f(rows):
      return rows.loc[[rows['width'].idxmax()]] 

  print(df.groupby(['date'], as_index=False).apply(f))

             date    mix  width
  0 4 2014-01-31    FMS     22
  1 1 2014-11-26      0     20
  2 3 2015-05-11  OPSTC     24
  3 2 2015-08-13      M     20
  4 0 2016-07-10      M     20
  ```
- Ok, so the `dtypes` make sense again, but you haven't eliminated anything because you grouped by `date` which where all unique.  Not sure what you wanted here but this is a guess.

  ```
  df.query('width == @df.width.max()')
  # equivalently
  # df[df.width == df.width.max()]  

          date    mix  width
  3 2015-05-11  OPSTC     24
  ```

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up. No, I had more than one row in each group (some rows were forms that were incompletely filled out) but I removed these to simplify; removing them didn't make the effect go away.